# Omni completion Pattern not found - Error loading rails environment

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-ruby

I'm trying to make Omni completion work with my Ruby files, but it only works with Ruby's core libraries; for instance, after typing

```
String.<C-X><C-O>
```

i get all Ruby's `String` methods, but trying to omni complete from any local class (for instance: `MyClass.<C-X><C-O>`) doesn't display any methods and, instead, shows me the following message:

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

Upon further inspection (i.e. using vim debug) i found that the rails environment is not loading properly; this is the error log (just relevant lines shown):

```
^[[31mCould not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources^[[0m
^[[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.^[[0m
calling function rubycomplete#Complete[22]..<SNR>116_ErrMsg
Error loading rails environment
.
.
.
calling function rubycomplete#Complete[22]..<SNR>116_ErrMsg
Problem loading class "MyClass", was it already completed?
function rubycomplete#Complete[22]..<SNR>116_ErrMsg returning #0
```

But running `gem list json` shows:

```
json (2.2.0, 2.0.2, 1.8.6, 1.8.3)
```

So the gem is definitely there, but it seems that vim omni completion is not aware of it.

It seems that (after reading about similar issues) the ruby version used in the rails app must be the same used to compile vim, is this correct? Does anyone know a way around this?

This is in my .vimrc (only relevant lines):

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_object = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_objectspace = 1
```

I am using **macOS (Sierra)** and this is `vim --version` output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Mar 26 2019 01:54:59)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-1050
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            -farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +textprop
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +timers
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +title
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        -toolbar
-clientserver      +job               +perl              +user_commands
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +viminfo
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +windows
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -X11
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xim
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit  -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.3 -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc  -L/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.6
```